# Multiple share dialogs on single page - new Facebook api

Tags: facebook

This is a question about the new Facebook share dialog. Not the feed dialog or the sharer.php url.

From my research it looks like Facebook now forces you to use OG tags to share description, title, image etc in a share dialog. Which would be fine if I didn't need to have multiple shares on 1 page all sharing different information. The Facebook documentation hasn't proved very useful.

For example, I have a product list view, with say 10 products. Next to each is a share option that would ideally share the image of the product, a short description and its title.

Is there anyone out there that has done this that can help?

For reference this is what I am talking about https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: I'm also very interested in this. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Marco I used OG tags on the page that was being shared, not the page in which the share button was on. For example, the list view would have OG tags but the share buttons would be sharing links to pages with their own OG tags. Facebook uses these.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using normal share functionality with Facebook, but by adding OG tags to the page that was being shared.

I had OG tags on the page with the share buttons, in this example my product listings page. However I added OG tags to each of the product pages. I configured the share button to share this individual product page and not the list view. Facebook then picked up on the individual product page OG tags.